# WooCommerce Load More Button functionality problem

Tags: javascript, php, woocommerce

I have a load more button (using this tutorial: https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/load-more-posts-ajax.html) that I am using on a woocommerce product page.
It all works great apart from when I click load more, it loads the products above and the button and then the user has to scroll up to see the new products.

On clicking a second time, the next lot of products load between the 1st and 2nd load. You have to go and find them.

Does anyone have any ideas what might be causing this?
I can't show you a live view due to my site not being live or on staging yet.

**archive-product.php:**

```
<?php
/**
 * The Template for displaying product archives, including the main shop page which is a post type archive
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/archive-product.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version 3.4.0
 */

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

get_header( 'shop' );
?>

<div id="top"></div>

<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'store_sidebar' ) ) { ?>
    <ul data-aos="fade" id="secondary" class="aside sidebar">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'store_sidebar' ); ?>
    </ul>
<?php } ?>

<?php
/**
 * Hook: woocommerce_before_main_content.
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper - 10 (outputs opening divs for the content)
 * @hooked woocommerce_breadcrumb - 20
 * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_website_data() - 30
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content' );

?>

    <header data-aos="fade" class="woocommerce-products-header">
        <h1 class="woocommerce-products-header__title page-title"><?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h1>

        <?php
        /**
         * Hook: woocommerce_archive_description.
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description - 10
         * @hooked woocommerce_product_archive_description - 10
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description' );
        ?>
    </header>

    <?php
    if ( woocommerce_product_loop() ) {

        /**
         * Hook: woocommerce_before_shop_loop.
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_output_all_notices - 10
         * @hooked woocommerce_result_count - 20
         * @hooked woocommerce_catalog_ordering - 30
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' );

        woocommerce_product_loop_start();

        if ( wc_get_loop_prop( 'total' ) ) {
            while ( have_posts() ) {
                the_post();

                /**
                 * Hook: woocommerce_shop_loop.
                 */
                do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop' );

                wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );

            }
        }

        global $wp_query;
            if (  $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) {
                echo '<button class="misha_loadmore">Load more</button>';
            }


        echo '<div class="top">';
            echo '<a class="more-link" href="#top">Back to top <span class="arrow">↑</span></a>';
        echo '</div>';

        woocommerce_product_loop_end();

        /**
         * Hook: woocommerce_after_shop_loop.
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_pagination - 10
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop' );
    } else {
        /**
         * Hook: woocommerce_no_products_found.
         *
         * @hooked wc_no_products_found - 10
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_no_products_found' );
    }

    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_after_main_content.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end - 10 (outputs closing divs for the content)
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content' );

    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_sidebar.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_get_sidebar - 10
     */
    // do_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar' );
    ?>

    <?php
    get_footer( 'shop' );
```

**js:**

```
jQuery(function($){
        $('.misha_loadmore').click(function(){

            var button = $(this),
            data = {
                'action': 'loadmore',
                'query': misha_loadmore_params.posts,
                'page' : misha_loadmore_params.current_page
            };

            $.ajax({
                url : misha_loadmore_params.ajaxurl,
                data : data,
                type : 'POST',
                beforeSend : function ( xhr ) {
                    button.text('Loading...');
                },
                success : function( data ){
                    if( data ) {
                        button.text( 'Load more' ).next().before(data);
                        misha_loadmore_params.current_page++;

                        if ( misha_loadmore_params.current_page == misha_loadmore_params.max_page )
                        button.remove();
                    } else {
                        button.remove();
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

**functions.php**

```
// AJAX LOAD MORE - PRODUCTS PAGE
function misha_my_load_more_scripts() {

    global $wp_query;
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script( 'my_loadmore', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '_static/js/main.js', array('jquery') );

    wp_localize_script( 'my_loadmore', 'misha_loadmore_params', array(
        'ajaxurl' => site_url() . '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        'posts' => json_encode( $wp_query->query_vars ),
        'current_page' => get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1,
        'max_page' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
    ) );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_loadmore' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'misha_my_load_more_scripts' );

// AJAX HANDLER
function misha_loadmore_ajax_handler(){
    $args = json_decode( stripslashes( $_POST['query'] ), true );
    $args['paged'] = $_POST['page'] + 1;
    $args['post_status'] = 'publish';

    query_posts( $args );

    if( have_posts() ) :
        while( have_posts() ): the_post();
            wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
        endwhile;
    endif;
    die;
}

add_action('wp_ajax_loadmore', 'misha_loadmore_ajax_handler');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_loadmore', 'misha_loadmore_ajax_handler');
```

Answer (score 0):

In the js file, find:

```js
button.text( 'Load more' ).next().before(data);
```

Replace it with:

```js
button.text( 'Load more' ).prev().after(data);
```